# Is it possible to use phpDocumentator on Twig templates?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, phpdoc

I'm currently working on a Symphony project with Twig templates. In order to know what each template does I'm adding extensive comments on the files with descriptions, parameters, returns, etc...

I was hopping to be able to run [phpDocumentator](http://www.phpdoc.org) (or any other suitable tool) on these files and have an easily accessible documentation for all our developers, however every time I run the following command:

```
php phpDocumentor.phar -d src/dir1/dir2/CoreBundle/Resources/views/ -t docs/api/ -v
```

I get a nice Exception as result:

```
[Exception]
No parsable files were found, did you specify any using the -f or -d parameter?
```

I know the docBlock should looks like `/** comment */` but comments on Twig looks like `{# comment #}`.

Is there a way/tool to be able to produce these documentation? If so, how do I do it?

Thanks

Comment: I'm almost sure that there is not.  Docblocks need PHP code elements to tie themselves to, so even putting proper docblocks in those twig files would not likely give you any output.  At best, a file-level docblock could succeed, but that's it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no “proper” way, but you could apply a pretty rotten hack:

1. you copy files to a temporary location …
2. … and replace the twig comments with PHP tags and comments.
3. then you run phpDocumentor on those files.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

targetpath="/tmp/phpdoc"
[ -d "$targetpath" ] && rm -r $targetpath
mkdir -p $targetpath

for twigfile in $(find src/ -name '*.html.twig'); do
    newtwigfile="$targetpath/${twigfile//\//_}.php"
    perl -pe 's|{#|<?php /*|g' $twigfile | perl -pe 's|#}|*/ ?>|g' > $newtwigfile
done

php phpDocumentor.phar -d $targetpath -t docs/api/ -v
```

This may need some tweaking in regard to what phpDocumentor accepts as valid comment blocks.

Before:

```
<div>
    {#
        This is the glorious lorem ipsum.
    #}
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
    eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
</div>
```

After:

```
<div>
    <?php /*
        This is the glorious lorem ipsum.
    */ ?>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
    eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
</div>
```

The downside of this, like of any hack, is that you need to know about this “processing” when you write your Twig comments.